# Why doesn' this observable react?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

The observable `this.currentNodeFilters$` is defined in `ngOnChanged` because it uses an `Input()` (`this.node`) pushed from a parent component using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (immutable object).

This `this.currentNodeFilters$` is used with current `queryParams` in `combineLatest`.
I'm expecting that on any changes from `this.currentNodeFilters$` or `queryParams`, the observable `this.currentFilters$` to react. But nothing happens.

**Question: Why is it not reacting to the changes ?**

Here is my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'filter-content',
  templateUrl: './filter-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-content.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class FilterContentComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentNodeFilters$: Observable<any>;
  public currentFilters:any;

  @Input() node;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.currentNodeFilters$ = Observable.of({
        "params": {
          "nodes": this.node.id
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const queryParams$ = this.route.queryParams;

    // On regarde les queryParams pour construire currentFilters
    Observable.combineLatest(this.currentNodeFilters$, queryParams$, (currentFilter, queryParams) => {
        const p = Object.keys(queryParams).map(key => {
          const params = {};
          params[key] = queryParams[key];
          return Object.assign({}, {"params": params})
        })

        return Object.assign({}, currentFilter, p);
      })
      .subscribe(currentFilters => this.currentFilters = currentFilters)

   }
}
```

And the hml file subscribing

```
node: {{node | json}} from filter-content<br>
currentNodeFilters$: {{currentNodeFilters$ | async | json}}<br>
currentFilters: {{currentFilters | json}}
```

Comment: Did you subscribed to the observable ?

Comment: Yes in the html. I'm going to edit the message to add it.

Comment: In my book, combineLatest takes two observables as argument, and a function that combines their events. map() takes a function accepting an event, not two values.

Comment: It looks like the square brackets are missing from the array destructuring: `.map(([currentFilter, queryParams]) => {`

Comment: I made some changements to the code to reflect what I have now. You both had good points but it did not solve the problem. In html, `node` and `currentNodeFilters$` are reacting but `currentFilters` is not. Why not, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is that your redefining the currentNodeFilters$ observable on every ngOnChanges. While instead you should be pushing a new value through the observable every time your ngOnChanges method has been called. Instead, you should be using a Subject if you want to do something like this. Your code would look like this:

```
// Create a subject instead of an observable
public currentNodeFilters$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
public currentFilters:any;

@Input() node;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnChanges() {
    // next the value through the subject
    this.currentNodeFilters$.next{
        "params": {
          "nodes": this.node.id
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. Fist time I use subject(). I guess that explains some of the issues I have with RxJS.

Comment: You should see the difference between an observable and a subject as: A subject is where you are the producer of values, an observable is where someone else (being Angular, RxJS itself, ...) is the producer and determines the values.